# Calling function for filtering

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

This function "karusell:isCurrentDateTimeBetweenDates" never gets called.  Why cant i use it for filtering? If a call i alone and store it in a variable it work. The value of the variable is false.

```
 <xsl:variable name="bannerList" select="verticaldata/contents/content[ karusell:isCurrentDateTimeBetweenDates( 'Thursday', '01' ,  'Friday', '03') ][position() &lt;= 5]" />
```

Edit:
How can the string be returned?

The filtering

The function

```
<xsl:function name="karusell:isCurrentDateTimeBetweenDates">    
    <xsl:param name="startDay"/>
    <xsl:param name="startHour" />
    <xsl:param name="endDay"/>
    <xsl:param name="endHour" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentDateTime" select="current-dateTime() " />


    <xsl:variable name="todayIndex" select="karusell:getDayIndex(format-dateTime($currentDateTime , '[F]'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="startDayIndex" select="karusell:getDayIndex($startDay)" />
    <xsl:variable name="endDayIndex" select="karusell:getDayIndex($endDay)" />

    <xsl:variable name="startDate" select= "$currentDateTime - ( $todayIndex - $startDayIndex )*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="endDate" select= "$currentDateTime + ( $endDayIndex - $todayIndex )*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>


    <xsl:variable name="startDateTime" select="format-dateTime($startDate, concat('[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T', $startHour ,':00:00')) cast as xs:dateTime"/>  
    <xsl:variable name="endDateTime" select="format-dateTime($endDate, concat('[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T', $endHour ,':00:00')) cast as xs:dateTime"/>  

    <xsl:value-of select="$currentDateTime &gt;= $startDateTime and $currentDateTime &lt; $endDateTime" />
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Consider to show us minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. I am afraid with just that snippet it is hard to help? So how does the function code look? How do you notice that the function is not called? The value of which variable is false? The `bannerList` variable should be a sequence of `content` elements, not true or false.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that my function was return the String 'false' not the boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xsl:sequence`, not `xsl:value-of` to return values of the data type your expression has. So replace

```
<xsl:value-of select="$currentDateTime &gt;= $startDateTime and $currentDateTime &lt; $endDateTime" />
```

with

```
<xsl:sequence select="$currentDateTime &gt;= $startDateTime and $currentDateTime &lt; $endDateTime" />
```

Additionally you can get better error diagnosis if you define the return type of your function with `<xsl:function name="pf:foo" as="xs:boolean">..</xsl:function>`.